# Is there a way to tell Eclipse to "Save all" before building?

Tags: java, eclipse, config

Does anyone know if there's a way to get Eclipse to do a "Save all" before building java code? (I don't use the "Build automatically" option, I'm talking when you use "Ctrl+B" to do a build all)

I've dug thru the preferences, and can't seem to find anything, so I figured I'd check the hive mind at Stack Overflow just in case.

I'm using Ganymede, V3.4.1, Build id: M20080911-1700, if it's relevant.

Thanks in advance,
Dave Mackie

Comment: I'm not familiar with one, but is it that much of a hassle to hit the save-all combination first?

Comment: I thought it had to save all before a build anyways?

Comment: You can also get Eclipse to perform a Save Action: it can reformat your code, remove unused imports, convert for loops to enhanced for loops etc. Very useful indeed.

Comment: I always have several files open, and inevitably I forget to save one of them (I'm just not in the habit of doing Ctrl+Shift+S)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Under preferences General->Workspace,  there's an "Save automatically before build" option.