# Eclipse - Galileo IDE force save of changed files before build?

Tags: eclipse, build, galileo

When I used previous versions of Eclipse (e.g. Ganymede/Europa) if I had edited a file and then attempted a build Eclipse would prompt me to save first.

Since I updated to Galileo (Build id: 20090920-1017 & just checked for updates) when I build I'm not prompted to save first.  Perhaps the dialog had a checkbox for "don't tell me again" which I mistakenly checked on???

I figure it is just a preference setting some where but I can't seem to find it, search in Preferences for 'save' and for 'build' but did not find it.  I tried "Save automatically before build" but that actually did not work for me, and isn't really what I was looking for anyways.

Any ideas?

thanks.

**Edit:**  I'm actually using an Ant script to 'build' (right click on script and Run As...Ant Build).  So perhaps my original wording was a bit off base since I did not state how I was building.

Comment: you don't use automatic builds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell Eclipse to "Save all" before building?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480891/is-there-a-way-to-tell-eclipse-to-save-all-before-building)

Answer (score 7):

It's under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Save automatically before build.  This works for me if I'm doing an Eclipse build (Project -> Build All).  Is that how you're building?

Comment: The OP did mention that setting, adding it wasn't "really what I was looking for anyways."

Comment: Now that you mention it I'm actually running an Ant script to build...which I should have stated in the question, just got into the habit of calling that a 'build'.  This probably changes the nature of the question.

Comment: Yeah, the preferences refer to Eclipse's built-in automatic build.  This bug report sounds like your problem (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282581) -- it is supposedly fixed in Eclipse 3.5.2, but I haven't tested that.  Perhaps you can give that a try.

Comment: Actually, I think 3.5.1 is the current release version.  Might require a dev build to check this out.

Answer (score 3):

As mention in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg26964.html), the only other options (other than the "Save automatically before build") which actually prompt for the user for file saving are:

```
> Run/Debug > Launching > Save required dirty editors before launching
> Run/Debug > Launching > [x] Build (if required) before launching
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of VonC looks great, but does not work as it seems (Eclipse 3.5.1.R35x_v20090910 on WinXP-Pro-32). However Eclipse and I seem to think differently about what is a "required dirty editor" :-(  --

Would be nice if it would be possible to define a scope of resources to check for dirtyness for every single launch configuration -- with "containing project & refernced projects" as the default setting.

But it looks like 3.5.2 fixes this problem.