# Eclipse doesn't save files before running, debugging,

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, ide

Normally Eclipse saves my unsaved files before starting to debug or run a ant script. This isn't working anymore.

The general -> safe before build is ticked. I have cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try these things? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955489/eclipse-galileo-ide-force-save-of-changed-files-before-build

Answer (score 34, accepted):

FailedDev pointed me to a thread talking about these kind of issue. Going under Window -> Preferences -> run/debug -> launch -> save dirty... did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Recently this was happening to me which I found really really annoying on my eclipse 3.8.1 running on Ubuntu 13.4. Below trick fixed it.

Window -> Preferences -> run/debug -> launching > check the optoin: Build (if required) before launching